# I am trying to create a parallel implementation for selection sort but it ends up slower than serial

Tags: java, parallel-processing, selection-sort

For my parallel computing class I have to think and create a parallel implementation of the selection sort algorithm. The idea is to be able to scale it to multiple threads so that it becomes faster than the serial implementation.

My idea was as follows:
[Parallel selection sort idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocux7.png)

I have created the following implementation over the last few days but it is much slower than the serial algorithm. Whenever I use more threads it is also much slower vs when I use one thread. This is the first time I am working with threads as well so I am not sure if I implemented that correctly.

SelectionSort.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SelectionSort {
    private static final int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final int NUMBER_COUNT = 10000;
    private static List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int[][] splitArray;
    private static List<Integer> lowestNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Integer> numbers = Numbers.GenerateNumber(NUMBER_COUNT);

        class Lowest {
            synchronized int getLowest(int index) {
                int lowestInArray = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for (int i = 0; i < splitArray[index].length; i++) {
                    if (splitArray[index][i] < lowestInArray) {
                        lowestInArray = splitArray[index][i];
                    }
                }
                return lowestInArray;
            }
        }

        Lowest lowest = new Lowest();

        class SelectionSortThread extends Thread {
            private int splitArrayIndex;

            private SelectionSortThread(int splitArrayIndex) {
                this.splitArrayIndex = splitArrayIndex;
            }

            public void run() {
                lowestNumbers.add(lowest.getLowest(splitArrayIndex));
            }
        }

        long startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_COUNT; i++) {
            List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
            splitArray = fillSplitArray(availableProcessors, numbers);
            lowestNumbers.clear();

            for (int j = 0; j < availableProcessors; j++) {
                if(splitArray[j] != null) {
                    threads.add(new SelectionSortThread(j));
                }
            }

            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.start();
            }

            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }

            int lowestInArray = getLowest(lowestNumbers);
            numbers = swap(numbers, lowestInArray);
            sortedList.add(numbers.get(0));
            numbers.remove(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted list: " + Arrays.toString(sortedList.toArray()));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime);
    }

    private static int getLowest(List<Integer> lowestNumbers) {
        int lowestInArray = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Integer lowestNumber : lowestNumbers) {
            if (lowestNumber < lowestInArray) {
                lowestInArray = lowestNumber;
            }
        }
        return lowestInArray;
    }

    private static List<Integer> swap(List<Integer> list, int lowest)
    {
        int n = list.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(list.get(i) == lowest) {
                Collections.swap(list, 0, i);
                return list;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    static int[][] fillSplitArray(int arrayAmount, List<Integer> listToUse) {
        if (listToUse.size() == 0) {
            return new int[0][0];
        }

        int splitLength = (int) Math.ceil((double) listToUse.size() / (double) arrayAmount);
        int[][] splits = new int[arrayAmount][];

        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listToUse.size(); i++) {
            if (k == splitLength) {
                k = 0;
                j++;
            }
            if (splits[j] == null) {
                int remainingNumbers = listToUse.size() - i;
                splits[j] = new int[Math.min(remainingNumbers, splitLength)];
            }
            splits[j][k++] = listToUse.get(i);
        }
        return splits;
    };
}
```

Numbers.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Numbers {
    static List<Integer> GenerateNumber(int numberCount) {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = numberCount; i > 0; i--) {
            temp.add(i);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing totally wrong or that I could improve? I am expecting the parallel implementation to be faster than the serial one but so far this is not the case. It is currently a lot slower.

Comment: Long story short, yes your are totally wrong. You run thread for each number in your input. It take enormous amount of resources and then you ignore all that effort and sort it in single thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @talex , do you have any idea on how I could use just a few threads to accomplish this? I have been trying for so long but I cannot figure it out

Comment: Selection sort is bad algorithm to make it parallel. Try merge sort.